# Boolean expression tree with predicates?

Tags: design-patterns, expression-trees

I am trying to design an expression tree builder that can be used to build an expression tree that can be evaluated lazily with provided context (hash map). Required set of operators is `AND`/`OR`/`NOT`, `<`,`<=`,`>`,`>=`,`=`,`!=`, `in_range`(inclusive or not). Expression tree must support a short circuiting (not computing more than needed for the final result). Evaluation result is either true or false. Which nodes in my case must be intermediate and which are the leafs? I suppose
`AND`/`OR`/`NOT` are intermediate ones and predicates (`<`,`<=`,`>`,`>=`,`=`,`!=`, `in_range`) will be leaf nodes? Or each predicate will be represented as a subtree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did this for my employer.  I haven't talked to them about open-sourcing it yet, though, so I can't show you any code.  I can give you some advice, though.

- If you have magnitude comparisons, then some subexpressions must not have Boolean results:  If you write `a <= b`, then `a` and `b` are numbers or strings.  You will probably also want math so you can write `a <= b+1`, etc. My solution was that:

  - only the atoms are leaves (`a`, `b`, `1`, etc.)
  - parsing an expression or subexpression produces a *typed* compiled expression object.  It is either known to produce a Boolean, string, or numeric result, or it may produce anything.  `a < b`, for example, is known to produce a Boolean result.
  - An expression that is used as a predicate is invalid unless it is known to produce a Boolean result.
- Since you will be taking arbitrary hashmaps as input, you need to think about how to handle nulls.  I suggest you do it the way SQL does it (the hard thinking has already been done), and add `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` to your language.

Comment: Thanks. How do you handle short circuiting for pure boolean expressions?

Comment: Parsing an expression returns a compiled expression (basically an AST).  It has a methods `asPredicate(input)` and `asValue(input)` that return functions that evaluate the expression on a given input.  You could alternatively do methods `evaluateAsPredicate(input)` and `evaluateAsValue(input)`.  Either way, if you evaluate `a and b`, and `a` is false, it just doesn't evaluate `b`.  You don't short circuit the parse, just the evaluation.

Comment: I have another question. How do you represent set operations in the tree (e.g. intersection)? I suppose as a subtree for each of intermediate node of special type?

Comment: Where do the sets come from?

Comment: That's not a part of original question, but i'm just curious, can be sets  represented the same way or not.

Comment: Sure, you can have subexpressions that return sets.   In my implementation, there are 7 kinds of sub-expression classified by what type they are known to return -- null, boolean, number, string, list, map, or any.